# error: incompatible types when initializing type

Tags: c, pointers, casting

```
error: incompatible types when initializing type 'REQ_ONE * {aka struct REQ_ONE *}' using type 'REQ_ONE {aka volatile struct REQ_ONE}'
 #define FIND_T(a, type)  (*((volatile type *)a))
```

I want to get the contents of `REQ_ONE`. Originally I was just using:

`REQ_ONE *reqReg = FIND(ADDRESS)`

but my code analyser complained `pointer to void not allowed` . So I want to cast the type of the struct to get around this. I have lots of different structs so I want to just use one macro:

```
REQ_ONE *reqReg = FIND_W(ADDRESS, REQ_ONE);
```

and pass the type parameter I want to deference. However I am getting the above compilation error, before I even get to see if my analyzing tool is satisfied.

```
#define TEST_ADDR   0x00652000UL
#define ADDRESS     0x00000500UL

#define FIND(v) ((void *)TEST_ADDR + v)      
#define FIND_T(a, type)  (*((volatile type *)a))
#define FIND_W(val, dataType) FIND_T(FIND(val), dataType) 

typedef struct testing_t {
  union {
    struct {
      uint32_t avr_one :  4;
      uint32_t avr_one :  4;
      uint32_t avr_one :  4;
      uint32_t avr_one :  2;
      uint32_t bcr_one :  4;  
      uint32_t test_one : 4;  
      uint32_t reserved :  1; 
      uint32_t bcr_three : 2; 
      uint32_t reserved1 :  1;
      uint32_t test_one :  3;
      uint32_t avg  : 2;
      uint32_t reserved2 : 1;
    };
    uint32_t VALUE32;
  };
} REQ_ONE;
```

Comment: Appears to be missing code that actually does something

Comment: In the `FIND_W` expansion, `type` should be `dataType`.

Comment: @Steve Ithe line of code that is doing something is in the question

Comment: @PaulOgilvie yes corrected thanks sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding this yields:

```
REQ_ONE *reqReg = (*((volatile REQ_ONE *)((void *)0x00652000UL + 0x00000500UL)))
```

and there is one `*` too many so you dereference what you are pointing to and want to assign that to a pointer type variable. The error is in:

```
#define FIND_T(a, type)  (*((volatile type *)a))    // wrong
#define FIND_T(a, type)  ( ((volatile type *)a))    // no dereference
```

Comment: Great that passes the compilation thanks very much, analyser still complains about pointer to void not allowed. I thought this would have got around that warning.

Comment: That may be because you are adding a value to a void pointer, so the compiler does not know the size of the data type pointed to when calculating the addition. Were it for example a pointer to int, then it would add `sizeof(int)*0x00000500UL`.

Comment: So the way the code is currently I can't avoid that warning?

Comment: What do you want to do with that absolute address and that addition to it?